# Is there a faster way to fill in a set of missing faces?

Tags: modeling

Is there a faster way to create faces to fill the row than I have to do it one by one?

Example of selecting 4 vertices and create a face with *Vertex > New Edge/Face from Vertices* (<kbd>F</kbd>) in *Edit* mode:

[image: One]

[image: Two]

[image: Three]

Comment: You mean you want to fill in each of the faces? Select the whole (set of) edges on either side, right click and select "bridge edge loops", or select the whole (open) loop and select `face > grid fill`

Answer (score 4):

If you select just the far edge and hold your mouse in the direction you want to create a face, you can repeatedly press (or even just hold down) <kbd>F</kbd>:

[image]