# removing head from character mesh using another head mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I have a mesh of a character body with a head. I also have another mesh with just the head (and part of the neck):

[image]

I would like to "cut off" the head of the character body (bottom mesh) so that the head mesh (top mesh) fits exactly in the empty space. Is there any way that I can tell Blender to cut exactly that head/neck shape out of the bottom mesh?

I tried to do this by manually deleting vertices, but I can't do it beacuse the faces don't line up exactly where I need to cut so I end up cutting too much.

Here is a close-up when the heads are stacked on top of each other. You can see the triangle faces on the body mesh don't match up exactly to the shaded gray area where the "head mesh" is sitting. If I try deleting vertices, it will delete the triangle faces leaving holes past the shaded gray area.

[image]

I also tried using a Boolean modifier when the 2 heads were stacked on top of each other but it didn't seem to work. I'm new to Blender and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How dense are the meshes? If you cut too much you could fill it up if the meshes are not too dense.

Comment: How would I fill it up if I cut too much? I posted a close-up image of the heads stacked on top of each other showing the problem.

Comment: I would convert the tris to quads (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5539/107598) and then delete one of the edge loops. That's a row of faces that goes around the neck. Hover the mouse over the head and press L to select the head and delete it. Then move the new head in position, join the objects (Ctrl+J), and fill the deleted edge loop between it and the body (https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/217892/107598). With the Smooth brush (Sculpt mode) you can smooth the transition. Just keep in mind the edit will mess up the UV maps (textures).

Answer (score 0):

I think your best solution is brute vertex editing. Delete the head you want to get rid of by circle selecting the vertices and creating as smooth a transition as possible. In edit mode (of the body) you can even place the new head exactly where you want it. You can then refine the vertices and begin stitching them together.

A more complicated, but possibly faster, way would be to isolate the neck loop on the replacement head, separate it from the new head, convert it from a mesh into a curve, place it exactly above the body where you're going to be putting it (having already mostly removed the old head, and then using "Knife Project" to cut new geometry around the neck hole. You'll still have issues marrying the heights of the different vertices, which you'll have to do by hand, but it should be pretty closely aligned.

Good luck!

Hi, to follow up: You select the ring of vertices, hit [shift]+[D], then [P] to separate them from the new head object. Choose "by selected." Then click off. Select the ring of vertices that you've separated and go to OBJECT>CONVERT TO>CURVE

You will be left with a curve, which you can then use for knife project.

Comment: Why and how do you convert the mesh into a curve? A single edge loop?