# I can't find a way to fill this specific gap

Tags: modeling, faces

so i'm trying to do this kind of triangular thingy but, I can't fill this little gap in the middle of the model, I already tried hitting F but it just say's that there are no faces to fill, even though I selected the two faces that are the most closer to the gap I want to fill, is there another hotkey I don't know about or a modifier for this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Select the two Edges you want to span with a new face, and then 'f'.  Sort of like https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/217895/111042

Comment: BTW, select the edges you want to fill, not the faces.  Otherwise the Fill Vertices already sees existing faces that connect your vertices (from the too many vertices you are selecting) and assumes there's nothing to Fill.   You can first clean up (remove) any unwanted faces.

Comment: maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/